How do I disable shortcut long-press ctrl "Layout Options" in MS Word?
Going nuts for the long-press on ctrl keyboard shortcut, continually interrupting my workflow in MS Word documents.

Anyone of you smart creatures know how to permanently disable this?
I have tried other community blogs' suggestions to uncheck "Show Mini Toolbar on selection" from File > Options > Word Options > General navigation. That has not changed anything. Unless I need to do something extra from that point?

Does https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d help?
